# ZEIT Now Serverless Functions - Routes with Parameters

Tags: javascript, express, routes, serverless, vercel

I created 4 serverless routes

- /api/list (GET)
- /api/add (POST)
- /api/update/:id (PUT)
- /api/remove/:id (DELETE)

I included them in the api/now.json file like this:

```
{"src": "/api/list", "dest": "./list.js", "methods": ["GET"]},
{"src": "/api/add", "dest": "./add.js", "methods": ["POST"]},
{"src": "/api/update/*", "dest": "./update.js", "methods": ["PUT"]},
{"src": "/api/remove/*", "dest": "./remove.js", "methods": ["DELETE"]}
```

The /api/list and /api/add routes which don't use parameters are working, but /api/update and /api/remove aren't working, because I probably didn't use the regex on the api path in the above quoted now.json file correctly.

The handler for the router looks like this (only the relevant path)

```
app.put('/api/update/:id', (req, res) => {
  ...
});
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `src` is the incoming request path that you want to match, and `dest` is the file that should execute.

That means you don't need any routes for your first two because visiting `/api/list` will execute the function in your file `/api/list.js` and `/api/add` will execute `/api/add.js`.

You can use [rewrites](https://zeit.co/docs/configuration#project/rewrites) in a `now.json` file to define routes similar to express patterns:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/update/:id", "destination": "/api/update" },
    { "source": "/remove/:id", "destination": "/api/remove" }
  ]
}
```

An example function in `/api/remove.js` would look like:

```js
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.query;
  res.send('Removing ID ' + id);
});
```

Alternatively, you could name your file `/api/remove/[id].js` and then you wouldn't need to define `rewrites` configuration at all. This is called [Path Segments](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction#path-segments).

Comment: Do rewrites support methods?

Comment: No. Instead you should return HTTP 405 Status [Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) if you have a function that doesn't support the requested method.